# Retrofit nested call not being cancelled

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a fragment with a nested retrofit call inside an on response callback. I am cancelling both requests on the onStop method of the fragment, which according to the logs and debugging it's being call thus the cancel() for both retrofit calls are being called too.

Here is the code for the nested calls

```
serviceRequestTypesResponseCall.enqueue(new RetrofitCallback<ServiceRequestTypesResponse>(retrofit) {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(RetrofitResult<ServiceRequestTypesResponse> result) {

            // get url from response and enqueue nested call
            detailedServiceRequestTypeCall = scfServiceV2.getRequestType(result.getRequestTypeUrl());
            detailedServiceRequestTypeCall.enqueue(new RetrofitCallback<DetailedServiceRequestType>(retrofit) {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(RetrofitResult<DetailedServiceRequestType> result) {
                    // this is being reached when cancelled
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(RetrofitResult<DetailedServiceRequestType> error) {
                    // do something
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(RetrofitResult<ServiceRequestTypesResponse> error) {
            // do something
        }
    });

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // nested call
    if(detailedServiceRequestTypeCall != null) {
        detailedServiceRequestTypeCall.cancel();
    }

    // outer call
    if(serviceRequestTypesResponseCall != null) {
        serviceRequestTypesResponseCall.cancel();
    }
}
```

The nested call gets a dynamic url from the outer call response, thus this is how it's defined in it's retrofit interface

```
@GET
Call<DetailedServiceRequestType> getRequestType(@Url String url);
```

also, this is how I am handling Retrofit cancellation in my custom callback class

```
public abstract class RetrofitCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    private static final String TAG = "RetrofitCallback";

    protected final Retrofit retrofit;

    public RetrofitCallback(Retrofit retrofit) {
        this.retrofit = retrofit;
    }

    public abstract void onResponse(RetrofitResult<T> result);
    public abstract void onFailure(RetrofitResult<T> error);

    @Override
    public final void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
        onResponse(new RetrofitResult<>(retrofit, response));
    }

    @Override
    public final void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
        if (call.isCanceled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Cancelled => " + call.request().toString());
        } else {
            onFailure(new RetrofitResult<T>(t));
        }
    }
}
```

The fragment is inside a bottombar navigation (https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar[bottombar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar)) which basically replaces the fragments upon tab selection. The requests are happening when the fragment gets displayed so switching the fragments quickly so to not give time for the nested call to finish reproduces this issue.

The logcat only shows the cancel log for the outer call. Not sure why I am not getting the same for the nested call despite being explicitly cancelled . This causes the request to finish and try to do some ui related logic and reference the activity which is no longer available because the fragment has been replaced when switching fragments

Comment: This could sound crazy, but consider next order.

1. onStop
2. detailedServiceRequestTypeCall is null yet, so no cancel
3. serviceRequestTypesResponseCall onResponse
4. detailedServiceRequestTypeCall  created
5. serviceRequestTypesResponseCall cancelled.

Could you please try to call outer call cancellation first?

Comment: Already tried that, didn't work. The issue seems to happen when the outer call finishes (**serviceRequestTypesResponseCall.isCanceled()** and **serviceRequestTypesResponseCall.isExcecuted()** are **true**), onStop occurs and the nested call is still not created which I guess happens right next. There is some small logic that needs to happen before actually executing the nested call, something like checking the size of the list and get a list item with the dynamic url to call to. Thus when the nested call happens, then the fragment is no longer attached to the activity.

Comment: I think I can workaround it by checking if the serviceRequestTypesResponseCall.isCanceled() is true before creating the nested call. The question would be: why is it still calling the onResponse method in the Calback if the call is apparently cancelled?. I didn't figure out yet if there is another way to do this

Comment: Any solution for the nested call?